# Javascript Line break detection and line break preservation

Tags: javascript, line-breaks, capitalize

I wrote a function to capitalize each letter at the beginning of each sentence.  I want to output the text that originally has line breaks to a text-area from a text-area. The output text should preserve these line breaks. But my code is ignoring all the linebreaks. Can you help me with this? My code:

```
btnPara.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  function paragraphMode(str) {
    var splitPara = str
      .split(/\r?\n/)
      .join(" ")
      .split(". ")

      .map(
        (sentence) => sentence.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + sentence.substring(1)
      );

    return splitPara.join(". ");
  }
  outputText.value = paragraphMode(inputText.value);
});
```

Comment: `.split(/\r?\n/)` would remove those line break

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to process newline, you only need to find all occurrences of first char after a `.`. For example, you can use `/(^|\.)\s*(\w)/g`

```js
const process = s => s.replace(/(^|\.)\s*(\w)/g,w=>w.toUpperCase())

console.log(process("abc.    def .  g   h . ijk lm. \n O \n pq\nR\ns"))
console.log(process("some text is\nwritten here.  it doens't\nproperly capitalize sentences.\ncan we fix it?")) // example sentence suggested by @ Scott Sauyet
```

---

btw, for the same effect of your origin code (only one space/newline after a period is matched), you simply change `\s*` to `\r?[\n ]`

```js
const input = "abc.    def .  g   h . ijk lm. \n O \n pq\nR"
const result = input.replace(/(^|\.)(\r?\n| )(\w)/g,w=>w.toUpperCase())
console.log(result)
```

Comment: So much simpler than mine.  I will delete mine sometime soon.  But before then, you might want to swipe my test string.  It's easier to understand than the above.

Comment: Suggested test case: `"some text is\nwritten here.  it doens't\nproperly capitalize sentences.\ncan we fix it?"`

Comment: Or if you want to extend to handle `?` and `!`, then maybe this: `"some initial text is
written here.  it is wonderful\ntext!  but it doens't\nproperly capitalize sentences.\ncan we fix it?  let's see."`